# crawl link from site

Tags: c#, web-crawler

i have one issue. i want to crawl link from one site (sample: `www.x.com/date/counter of news`).
now, my solution is:

1- i have **lastest link** that stored in my database, like as below:
`www.x.com/2015/01/13/99901`

2- i get **newest link** from site, like as below:
`www.x.com/2015/01/12/99905`

3- i want to **loop** between *99901 ~ 99905* for generate link between above both link, like as below:

`www.x.com/2015/01/12/99901`
`www.x.com/2015/01/_( I don't know this day is /12 or /13 )_/99902`
`www.x.com/2015/01/_( I don't know this day is /12 or /13 )_/99903`
`www.x.com/2015/01/_( I don't know this day is /12 or /13 )_/99904`
`www.x.com/2015/01/13/99905`

now, i know that when day of date changed ?!!

Comment: Could you put basic code of your project so we don't feel like we give you the answer for free.

Answer (score 0):

You should at first check what's response for non-existing page (e.g. 01/12/99999). Then you should loop over with "first" day, check the response, if you get the same response, add 1 to day and repeat until you receive expected response.